# How do you match the value of a capturegroup/variable?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression that will match palindromes 4 or more letters in length (so it would match 'civic' and 'noon' but not 'tot' or 'teach'. If a given string takes the form xy...yx, it will always be a palindrome. So far I have `^[(\w)(\w)][\2\1]$` but it isn't working. Am I correct in assuming that `\1` matches the VALUE of the first `\w` or does it just match the subexpression `\w`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
^(\w)(\w).?\2\1$
```

Guess you needed this.`[]` is not what you think.Moreover regex for detecting palindrome of any numbers is not possible.For `4 or 5` it can.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/mS3tQ7/5